# Mass Excel hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I've looked around and can't seem to find any help for what I am looking to do.

I have a document that I am using to record data related to repairs and such on machines.

All of my entries are done in a numeric order.

I have to scan hard copies in and hyperlink to them from the excel sheet.

All the files are named to me in a numerical order as well that matches the number in column A.

Is there a way to do this as a formula?

Comment: You should be able to utilize the hyperlink() function, including a formula for how the hyperlink is built.  If values are in columns A and B for naming, then you could have something similar to ="C://File/"&A&" "&B".pdf" in column C.  Then in column D you can =hyperlink() what is displayed in column C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HYPERLINK formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F).  The 1st parameter allows you to dynamically build up the URL to point to, so if you say you have the correct numbers already in a column, you can use that to build the URL.  Provided the URL for each scanned document can uniquely be derived using only that number, of course.

If the scanned documents are on the web, then you can use e.g.:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.myserver.com/scans/"&A4&".pdf","Scan nr. "&A4)
```

If they're on your own computer (or on a network drive), then you can use e.g.:

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///D:/scans/"&A4&".pdf","Scan nr. "&A4)
```

--- EDIT ---
As Cyril pointed out, you can also just use e.g.:

```
=HYPERLINK("D:\scans\"&A4&".pdf","Scan nr. "&A4)
```

which makes it a bit more readable.  Also note that Excel really likes to warn you when using these types of links ;)